# I am not able to show attributes table in QGIS,after I converted the file from DXF to shapefile

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, dxf

[image]

[image]

[image: w attribut]

I am not able to show attributes table in QGIS, after I converted the file from DXF to shapefile. 
the source of file was DGN so i saved it by bentley as DXF file .
to use on QGIS ,is it right way but the source of DGN it has already id for each line so why i do not have at the end

I used another DXF importer or converter to import my map but I found I have the map how it looks like but I am not able to see each line or select each line on the map.

by the way i have FME software if someone can provide me another method to convert from DGN to DWG OR DXF to read on QGIS
Could someone guide me?

Answer (score 1):

DXF doesn't have attributes as such.

You can save some information is some specific fields that will be kept in the DXF. For example a "layer" field will be kept.

So if you rename the attribute you want to keep to "layer" then export the dxf, then that will be saved.

If you want attributes you shouldn't be using a CAD format.

You can read a bit more on GIS to CAD transfer using ogr2ogr at: https://gisforthought.com/gis-to-cad-using-ogr2ogr-part-1-shp-to-dxf-with-contour-data/

Comment: but i have dgn format v7 ,so which format should i change to. and i want to keep all attributes as id of each line and so on .what is important for me to read the file on QGIS .so which format sufggest u to convert from dgn to .thanks

Comment: Just open the DXF in QGIS and have a look at the attribute table.

Comment: i used dxf import / convert but no attributes that show for me when i click right on the layer but i have all layers that i need .and the map it looks like the same on dgn file with all layers but when i click right on the layer in dfx file ,i do not see any show attribute table .do u have solution for it.thanks

Comment: Post a copy of the DXF file.